# pushing busybox into android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, busybox

I've downloaded the source for mips android and have done a "make" and got the emulator running. I want to push the busybox into the emulator. I've downloaded the static compiled busybox binary. Under which directory should I place this and what should I do to push the busybox into the emulator?

Comment: [Here](http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/14/android-busybox) you've got tutorial and binary for emulator. It worked for me.

Comment: i was able to push it into the emulator and did a chmod 775. Then when I gave ./busybox --install, it throws an error which says "./busybox: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected". How do I resolve this?

Comment: I did the same and no errors. Emulator 2.2. Have you created correct directory structure? Try to run /data/busybox/busybox --install

Comment: Yes I've created the directory structure correctly. The same error shows again. I have compiled the android sources with a cross compiler. And so used the same cross compiler for busybox code too. Does this have anything to do with the error?

Comment: I haven't compiled anything, just downloaded binary from the link I've provided and installed on emulator.

Answer (score 10):

1. Root your emulator
2. Download [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6408470/su-releases/su-2.3.6.1-ef-signed.zip)
3. Extract it then move `\system\lib\su` and `\system\app\superuser.apk` to your `adb` directory.
4. Run adb and then enter the following:

> ```
> adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system  
> adb push su /system/xbin/su  
> adb shell chmod 06755 /system  
> adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
> adb install superuser.apk
> ```

5. Then download busybox from [here](http://benno.id.au/android/busybox)
6. Move it to your adb directory
7. run adb and then enter:

> ```
> adb shell mkdir /data/busybox
> adb push busybox /data/busybox
> adb shell
> su
> cd /data/busybox
> chmod 775 busybox
> ./busybox --install
> busybox
> ```

Comment: ./busybox --install installs files in various locations. I got No such file or directory, Invalid cross-device link errors. I wanted to install in /data/busybox folder. So, I used the following command: `./busybox --install .`

Comment: I would advise against downloading mysterious dropbox files. Please be very careful when trying this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated instructions for 2023

Download busybox binary matching your AVD image architecture from https://github.com/meefik/busybox/tree/master/app/src/main/_libs. For example I downloaded the "arm64-v8a" directory to my desktop.

Execute the following commands (replace image name / device name with your own):

```bash
emulator -avd Pixel_6_API_31 -writable-system
adb -s emulator-5554 root
adb -s emulator-5554 remount
adb -s emulator-5554 push ~/Desktop/arm64-v8a/busybox /system/xbin/busybox
```

Now you can use busybox on your emulator:

```bash
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
emulator64_arm64:/ # busybox --help
BusyBox v1.34.1-meefik (2022-01-01 14:33:14 CST) multi-call binary.
...
```