# rm -rf on android using tasker

Tags: android, scripting, tasker

might be answered somewhere else, but searched for a good hour, with no luck.

what are the outputs the rm -rf command can give? both error and if successful.
i have a virus of some sort, in my rom on my phone, and its the only rom i have found to work, other than stock, but it installs an app on its own, luckily i have found out, it needs a certain directory, which i have access to, and the file it installs is in there, and needs to be in there for 30 min, not sure why but im okay with it, before it installs, so im currently making a script to run every 10 minutes to delete it, problem is, if the file is not there, it will stop the loop.

and while we are on the topic of creating things in tasker, what is the easiest way, to make a script run all the time?

Comment: i have since gotten a new phone, so the subject is no longer relevant.

sorry if i wasted some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use tasker for this - you can just put `rm -rf` on a cron... as far as outputs go, `rm -rf` will not give any output if you are root. It will just do as it is told. 
The only time it will complain is if it finds an immutable file, or if you manage to delete `rm` itself before it can finishing deleting stuff....

As far as crons go, read this to find out more about that:

[How to use crontab in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747880/how-to-use-crontab-in-android)

But, there is a 90% chance that what you see isn't actually a virus. 
If you wipe all your partitions and flash a new ROM, that should really set you at ease, since there aren't really any android rootkits known to mankind that could survive a complete wipe...
It is not uncommon for perfectly legitimate applications to create files they are missing, so I really suggest that you re-evaluate why you think that is a virus --- and then simply wipe all the partitions and reflash --- rest easy, it very likely is not a virus.

Comment: what i had was a virus, it kept installing random things. things i never allowed to be installed, because i dont use them, i found out a little later on, which app made the folder, and removed it, and i have had no problems since then. so it was some sort of virus. since it pretended to be a lockscreen, which i had no access too, and simply stated "lockscreen for android systems" as its purpose.

sorry for the long time until i made my reply, had forgot i made this post..