# Android kernel run fanotify without rooting?

Tags: android, c, linux, linux-kernel, fanotify

I would like to implement a [fanotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) (supported by kernel > 2.6.37 - shipped in Android 5+) interface for the Android x86 - at first for goldfish emulator. I like to use the tool [fsmon](https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2016/02/18/filesystem-monitor-tool-for-ios-and-android/) to start the filesystem monitor (a C program with basic structure to use the fanotify syscalls `fanotify_init(2)` and `fanotify_mark(2)`). I extended the fsmon code by own access-permissions. This permissions should be able to edited later by an system app in Android. (For example: I can choose later, which file types are denied)

The problem is following:

> "The other big drawback of fanotify is that it currently is root-only (CAP_SYS_ADMIN-only to be more specific). This means that only the root user can request to use the monitoring capabilities provided by fanotify [...]"
>   [[source]](http://www.lanedo.com/filesystem-monitoring-linux-kernel/)

A rooted phone is a must have? But is there not another way to run on/after kernel boot the fsmon binary **without** rooting the device?

My first thought was to execute a file/service after every boot by `init.d`. But to use it, you need a rooted phone. Then I found this: [init.d scripts support](http://www.naldotech.com/how-to-run-execute-init-d-scripts-android-no-root/):

> "If your device is rooted the scripts can be executed using superuser permissions, but normal users can do also."

But I cant't understand how this can work (I didn't test it yet) Could this be a possible solution? For running it on other devices (without installing this app), I need to understand how the app bypass the  problem. And `init.d` gets executed in the user-space, is it even possible to run the monitor there as root?

Next thought was to run a crontab, but same [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747880/how-to-use-crontab-in-android) - rooted phone.

Now I go one level deeper - linking/execute the binary (or the c code) in the kernel boot sequence.. I have to be honest - I'm not a professional kernel developer. I know, that I need the [execve](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/syscall-4.html) systemcall to run a file in kernel. But is my approach right? If this could be the right way, how can I communicate later with the system app? Do I need to create a small "database" from where both sides can access? Which way is the best to access the provided data from the system app? ([kernel-userspace-communication: Procfs, Sysfs, Configfs, ...](http://wiki.tldp.org/kernel_user_space_howto)) Where is the right place to start the monitor? (sure - after setting up the filesystem)

Or is it **absolutely not possible** to use fanotify **without rooting** the phone?

I would be very happy if someone can give me some tips...

Comment: Ok, for the communication between user-space and kernel-space: Is the Android specific Binder the right way to solve this problem? I will continue to research.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a feature that requires a permission (CAP_SYS_ADMIN or root) that is withheld from user and application processes by design. You either need a phone that provides this capability to designated applications or you need to root the phone. I do not know of any phones phones providing this capability, because it would enable an app to subvert the security of the system.

Comment: Okay that's an answer for me, thanks! I already suspected it's not possible... Then I will root the phone for this plan.